# How to return the number of different values in pandas dataframe as an integer

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to count how many different values exists in a pandas dataframe column and return it as an INTEGER. I need to store that number in a variable so I can use it later.

I tried this:

`count = pd.Series(table.column.nunique())`

I get the expected result, but as pandas series not as integer, so I can't use it later in my function.

I've also looked for something that could convert it into numeric, but I havn't found anything.

Comment: What is the first element of `count`?

Comment: `dict(table['column'].value_counts(dropna=False))` will give you a dictionary with `keys` as column value and `value` as count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your issue?

```
table['column'].nunique()
```